# Cannot make post request containing an array in node

Tags: node.js, express, post

I am a beginner who have been banging my head for days with this problem I got really really stuck with.

Basically I just want to make a post request using node and express. The object will be created dynamically, but this is my hard coded example. myObj contain an array because I want to do one insert to the database for each item later on server side.

```
let myObj = {
        id: 50,
        damage_type: ["missing", "broken", "light"]
      }

// Parse myObj to JSON string to be sent
let myjsonObj = JSON.stringify(myObj);
console.log(myjsonObj );
// {"poi":50,"damage_type":["missing","broken","light"]}
postDamage(myjsonObj )

function postDamage(damage) {
  $.post({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/damage',
    data: damage
  }).
  done(function (damage) {
    // Do things
}


router.post('/damage', (req, res) => 
{ 
  let data = req.body;
  console.log(data)

// This is what I get in the node terminal which is nonsense, I cannot work with 
{ '{"id":50,"damage_type":["missing","broken","light"]}': '' }

I expect it to look like {"id":50,"damage_type":["missing","broken","light"]}
So I can loop through the damage_type creating new objects with this structure
createSQLfunction({id:50, damage_type:"missing"})

});
```

If I dont stringify my myObj the node terminal is printing
`{poi:'50', 'damage_type[]: [ 'missing','broken','light']}` Where does the extra [] come from?!

What am I doing wrong not to be able to send an array inside an object to the server side?

Answer (score 0):

From the jquery website:

> data
>
> Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>
> Data to be sent to the
> server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.
> It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to
> prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If
> value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key
> based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

The `traditional` setting appears to be whether it url-encodes as `key[]=val1&key[]=val2` or just `key=val1&key=val2`. You can give it a try, YMMV.

Or you could make your life a lot easier and just serialize the json yourself, instead of messing with jquery's url-encoding.

*Edit: In answer to your question about best practices: Back before JavaScript form submissions became popular, the two standard ways of submitting a form were `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`. The latter was mostly used if you had file(s) you were submitting with a form.

However with the advent of JavaScript XHR (ajax) form submissions, it has become much more common/popular to use JSON instead of either of these formats. So there is absolutely nothing at all wrong with doing something like `data: JSON.stringify(object)` when you submit your data, and then just instruct your server to read the JSON.

In fact it's probably both easier and faster. And it is a very popular method, so no worries about going against modern best practices.

Comment: I want to use as much "best practice" as I can. Is it unusual to make a post request with array as on of the key value? It sounded straight forward but has become very difficult. I am doing it so I can make one post request with all the damages associated to id 50 instead of sending multiple post request. I tried that before but it did not work properly, order of execution got mixed up. 
Not sure how I would serialize it myself tbh. Would I not need to build the serialized string myself and send it as text?

Comment: Edited my answer to address your follow up questions. Yes, definitely avoid multiple POSTs...that would be extremely complex and inefficient.